# Can a jQuery .load -ed ID respond to click event?

Tags: jquery, events

Using jQuery, I've `$('content').load` -ed text into a class on my web page. The content includes a new ID which I would like to respond to a click event. Is this possible?
Here's the script...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("ul.nav li:eq(3)").click(function(){
         $('.content').load('gpstart.html #product').fadeIn('slow');
       });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either

```
$('.content').on('click', '#your-element-id', function(){  });
```

or

```
$('.content').delegate('click','#your-element-id', function(){  });
```

Try not delegating to the `document` as the event would have to bubble all the way up the DOM, since you know your element is inside the content then you can just delegate the event to that element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) methods to bind to click event for elements that will be created (loaded) in the future.

Comment: `.live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Also, `.delegate()` is not deprecated, but is superseded by `.on()` (since 1.7).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using **[jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#some_id', function() {
        // do something
    });

   $("ul.nav li:eq(3)").click(function(){
     $('.content').load('gpstart.html #product').fadeIn('slow');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but `.click(function () {})` is a shortcut for `.bind('click', function () {})` and `.bind()` only works for elements that are in the DOM when the event is bound.

jQuery >= 1.7

```
$(document).on('click', '#my-dynamicly-inserted-id', function () {
    //your click handler here for the `.load`-ed element
});
```

jQuery < 1.7

```
$(document).delegate('#my-dynamicly-inserted-id', 'click', function () {
    //your click handler here
});
```

I don't recommend using `.live()` as it's the same thing as `$(document).delegate()` and it is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7.